# Declaring an array of array using Objects

Tags: java

I'm trying to construct an array of array using Objects. I created the Object Block which contains multiple variables in it. I wrote:

```
Block[][] block = new Block[4][4];
```

Now I am having an error when I insert:

```
block[1][1] = new Block(); // As what I've understood, we still need 
                           // to create the object inside this specific block[][]
```

The error message is:

> Cannot find symbol, ']' expected and Invalid method declaration,
>   return type required

Comment: _Now I am having an error when I insert:_ what error?

Comment: Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What's the error message? Noone can help you if you don't provide all the information that you can provide, wether or not it seems important to you.

Comment: Does `Block()` have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: To "improve" @hmjd's question: Does `Block` have *visible* parameterless constructor?

Comment: The issue earlier was fixed by placing the snippet below in the main of my project...

Block[][] block = new Block[4][4];
        block[1][1] = new Block();

however, the question is that when I inserted the snippet in another class in the project, the code " block[1][1] = new Block();" is having an error (Cannot find symbol, ']' expected and Invalid method declaration, return type required). May I know the reason for this?

Comment: @JonaziAlmocera I added the error message to your question. I don't know why you've not added it 45min ago when the first people asked you to provide it?!

Comment: I apologize for that. I'm new here in stackoverflow, and I didn't notice that it would be much easier and understandable to add the error message at the original question above. I thought that you were referring to add the error here in the comments. I'm sorry for the hassle and for the late reply, I just had an urgent call.

Thanks for the edit. @FabianBarney

Comment: Np, but now go on and provide a complete program demonstrating the problem as Jon Skeet asked you 58mins ago.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. Next time I will...

I realized that I will be needing help by some time and this place is a very good place to learn and ask for guidance, might as well learn the different features for better interaction.

Answer (score 4):

It works for me

```
public class testProgram {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Block[][] block = new Block[4][4];
        block[1][1] = new Block();
        block[1][1].setName("Block 1 1");
        System.out.println(block[1][1].getName());

        block[1][2] = new Block();
        block[1][2].setName("Block 1 2");
        System.out.println(block[1][2].getName());
    }

    public static class Block {

        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a question. I tied this, and it's working. I placed this in my Main page. I think I'm noticing something, the error occured when I placed this syntax in another class. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @JonaziAlmocera: Hard to tell without the real code - but if `Block` is an innder class - it probably has something to do with needing an enclosing instance. Declare `Block` as `public static class Block { ... } ` instead of `public class Block { ... } ` (Note the difference is the *static* keyword)

Comment: I am not clear what your mean. I test these code in two different classes.

Comment: @JonaziAlmocera Go and provide us the error message you get. Then we can tell you what's your problem instead of making blind guesses.

Comment: I appreciate your help! (I didn't test yet the public static class Block, but I was thinking to use that) 

By the way, here is the actual code: 

In my Main:

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        
      Block[][] block = new Block[4][4];
      block[1][1] = new Block();
         block[1][2] = new Block();
        
        
    }
and it  works perfectly fine..


Continuation... (Sorry, I'm a newbie here at stack overflow)

Comment: I placed the code above in a class and the code is this:


public class GameWorld {

 
      Block[][] block = new Block[4][4];
      block[1][1] = new Block();
         block[1][2] = new Block();
        
        
        
    
}

And the error is "

Cannot find symbol, ']' expected and Invalid method declaration, return type required.

Comment: @Amit, I tried inseting statis in public static class Block and it's saying that "static cannot be inserted here"

Comment: @JonaziAlmocera: The `static` keyword can be used only if the class is an inner class. If it is not (which seems to be the case) - ignore that comment.